# Android: Error when updating database using a string

Tags: android, database, string

My database contains a list of concerts and I'm updating them based on the name column. When the update button is clicked, the column values of the given concert is passed in. However the update only works when the name column is a single number. If the name column is a string, or 2+ digit number, it crashes instantly and gives me the following errors.

```
11-17 13:14:51.325  12131-12131/com.example.msdproject I/test﹕ Update artist method: Value of name = test
11-17 13:14:51.325  12131-12131/com.example.msdproject I/test﹕ Update artist method: Value of venue = test venue
11-17 13:14:51.325  12131-12131/com.example.msdproject I/test﹕ Update artist method: Value of date = dd
11-17 13:14:51.325  12131-12131/com.example.msdproject I/test﹕ Update artist method: Value of comments = d
11-17 13:14:51.325  12131-12131/com.example.msdproject I/test﹕ DB Manager method: Value of name = test
11-17 13:14:51.325  12131-12131/com.example.msdproject I/test﹕ DB Manager method: Value of venue = test venue
11-17 13:14:51.325  12131-12131/com.example.msdproject I/test﹕ DB Manager method: Value of date = dd
11-17 13:14:51.325  12131-12131/com.example.msdproject I/test﹕ DB Manager method: Value of comments = d
11-17 13:14:51.325  12131-12131/com.example.msdproject E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) no such column: test
11-17 13:14:51.335  12131-12131/com.example.msdproject D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
11-17 13:14:51.335  12131-12131/com.example.msdproject W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41614ba8)
11-17 13:14:51.355  12131-12131/com.example.msdproject E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.msdproject, PID: 12131
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: test (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE Concert_Info SET date=?,venue=?,comments=?,name=? WHERE name=test
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.updateWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1572)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.update(SQLiteDatabase.java:1520)
        at com.example.msdproject.DBManager.updateConcert(DBManager.java:150)
        at com.example.msdproject.UpdateArtist.UpdateArtistButton(UpdateArtist.java:103)
        at com.example.msdproject.UpdateArtist$1.onClick(UpdateArtist.java:79)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-17 13:14:51.365  12131-12131/com.example.msdproject D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 591K, 4% free 17167K/17788K, paused 9ms, total 9ms
11-17 13:14:53.245  12903-12903/com.example.msdproject I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:320>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM Build: I0404c4692afb8623f95c43aeb6d5e13ed4b30ddbDate: 11/06/13
11-17 13:14:53.275  12903-12903/com.example.msdproject D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
```

What it is basically saying is that the column doesn't exist but I can't see why it's giving me this error as it recognises the column exists when I use a single number. I tried deleting by _id but that gave me the same result so I reverted back to deleting by the name column. Are there exceptions as to what can be passed into a database update function?

Here is the updateArtist class:

```
package com.example.msdproject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.sql.SQLException;

public class UpdateArtist extends Activity {

    DBManager db = new DBManager(this);

    public EditText nameTxt;
    public EditText venueTxt;
    public EditText dateTxt;
    public EditText commentsTxt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_update_artist);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        final long num = intent.getLongExtra("id", 1);

        try {
            db.open();
            Cursor c = db.getConcert(num);
            if (c.moveToFirst())
            {
                do
                {
                    String name = (c.getString(1));
                    String venue = (c.getString(2));
                    String date = (c.getString(3));
                    String comments = (c.getString(4));

                    TextView titleTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.updateTitle);
                    nameTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.updateName);
                    venueTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.updateVenue);
                    dateTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.updateDate);
                    commentsTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.updateComments);


                    titleTxt.setText(name);
                    nameTxt.setText(name);
                    venueTxt.setText(venue);
                    dateTxt.setText(date);
                    commentsTxt.setText(comments);

                    Button update = (Button)findViewById(R.id.updateConcertButton);
                    update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v)
                        {
                            if (nameTxt.getText().toString().isEmpty()  || venueTxt.getText().toString().isEmpty() ||
                                    dateTxt.getText().toString().isEmpty() || commentsTxt.getText().toString().isEmpty() )
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(UpdateArtist.this, "Error! Please fill in all fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                            else
                            {

                                String updatedName = nameTxt.getText().toString();
                                String updatedVenue = venueTxt.getText().toString();
                                String updatedDate = dateTxt.getText().toString();
                                String updatedComments = commentsTxt.getText().toString();

                                UpdateArtistButton(updatedName,updatedVenue,updatedDate,updatedComments);
                            }
                        }
                    });

                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }
        }

        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void UpdateArtistButton(String passedName, String passedVenue, String passedDate, String passedComments)
    {
        try
        {
            db.open();
            Log.i("test", "Update artist method: Value of name = " + passedName);
            Log.i("test", "Update artist method: Value of venue = " + passedVenue);
            Log.i("test", "Update artist method: Value of date = " + passedDate);
            Log.i("test", "Update artist method: Value of comments = " + passedComments);
            db.updateConcert(passedName,passedVenue, passedDate, passedComments);
            Toast.makeText(UpdateArtist.this, "Concert Updated!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            super.finish();
        }

        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        db.close();
    }
}
```

Here is the DBManager class:

```
package com.example.msdproject;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import java.sql.SQLException;


public class DBManager {

    public static final String COL_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String COL_NAME = "name";
    public static final String COL_VENUE = "venue";
    public static final String COL_DATE = "date";
    public static final String COL_COMMENTS = "comments";

    private static final String DB_NAME = "Concerts";
    private static final String DB_TABLE = "Concert_Info";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String DB_CREATE =
            "create table " + DB_TABLE + 
    " (_id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
            "name text not null, " +
            "venue text not null, " +
            "comments text not null, " +
            "date text not null);";

    private final Context context;

    private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DBManager(Context ctx)
    {
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    public static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context)
        {
            super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
        {
            db.execSQL(DB_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
        {
            /*
            //taken from YouTube Tutorial video
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("drop table if exists Concert_Info");
            onCreate(db);*/
        }
    }

    public DBManager open() throws SQLException
    {
        db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        //db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DB_TABLE + ";");
        return this;
    }

    public void close()
    {
        DBHelper.close();
    }

    public long insertConcert(String name, String venue, String date, String comments)
    {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(COL_NAME, name);
        initialValues.put(COL_VENUE, venue);
        initialValues.put(COL_DATE, date);
        initialValues.put(COL_COMMENTS, comments);
        return db.insert(DB_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    public boolean deleteConcert(String name)
    {
        return db.delete(DB_TABLE, COL_NAME + "=" + name, null) > 0;
    }

    public Cursor getAllConcerts() {
        return db.query(DB_TABLE, new String[]
                        {
                                COL_ROWID,
                                COL_NAME,
                                COL_VENUE,
                                COL_DATE,
                                COL_COMMENTS
                        },
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null
                );
    }

    public Cursor getConcert(long ROW_ID) throws SQLException
    {
        Cursor mCursor =
                db.query(DB_TABLE, new String[]
                        {
                                COL_ROWID,
                                COL_NAME,
                                COL_VENUE,
                                COL_DATE,
                                COL_COMMENTS
                        },
                        COL_ROWID + "=" + ROW_ID,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null
                );
        if (mCursor != null)
        {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }

        return mCursor;
    }

    public boolean updateConcert(String name, String venue, String date, String comments)
    {
        ContentValues updateValues = new ContentValues();
        updateValues.put(COL_NAME, name);
        updateValues.put(COL_VENUE, venue);
        updateValues.put(COL_DATE, date);
        updateValues.put(COL_COMMENTS, comments);
        Log.i("test", "DB Manager method: Value of name = " + name);
        Log.i("test", "DB Manager method: Value of venue = " + venue);
        Log.i("test", "DB Manager method: Value of date = " + date);
        Log.i("test", "DB Manager method: Value of comments = " + comments);
        return db.update(DB_TABLE, updateValues, "name"  + "=" + name, null) > 0;
    }

    public void reset () throws SQLException {
        db.delete(DB_TABLE, null, null);
        db.close();
        this.DBHelper.onCreate(this.db);
    }
}
```

Comment: try this  `return db.update(DB_TABLE, updateValues, "name='"+ name+"'", null) > 0;`

Comment: @MD ahhh thank you! I thought it might have been something to do with the delimiters but when I tried single quotes I kept getting a string literal error. I never thought of doing it like that. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

value should be quoted:

```
return db.update(DB_TABLE, updateValues, "name"  + "='" + name +"'", null) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem in your code is:
WHERE name=test

Your query is broken.

Is test a value or a name of a field? Depends on semantic of test you have 3 ways to solve this problem:

1. If it is a name of a sqlite-field, then your table is missing this field and you should add it to your sqlite-table.
2. Should be test a value, then you have to use ' around this.
3. If test is a variable from your java-code, then you have to insert value of this variable into the query with concatenation f.e.