# Simple android SQL query qeestion

Tags: android, sqlite

I made a Table like below

columns:

```
KEY_ID(AUTOINCREMENT AND PRIMARY KEY),
KEY_DATE, 
KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME, 
KEY_CATEGORY, 
KEY_COST, 
KEY_EXPLANATION
```

I want to update a row which matches the **KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME**

But it gives me error..

Now I have two rows in the table which have **AAA**, **BBB** as **KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME** each.

And following query gives me the error like below.

(`ai.getAccount_name()` is the target **KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME** value which is **AAA**.)

```
db.update(TABLE_AI, values, KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME + "=" + ai.getAccount_name(), null);
```

Error:

```
11-20 11:55:26.258: E/AndroidRuntime(1738): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: AAA (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM accountInfoTable WHERE account_name = AAA
```

Should I change the primary key from **KEY_ID** to **KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME**?

Or it is not related to the problem?

Comment: Use `db.update(TABLE_AI, values, KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME + "=" + ?, ai.getAccount_name());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this pass string value to `'`

```
db.update(TABLE_AI, values, KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME + "='" + ai.getAccount_name()+"'", null);
```

Comment: hmm..It still gives me error but I will look into it further

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26973682/android-error-when-updating-database-using-a-string?noredirect=1#comment42482634_26973682](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26973682/android-error-when-updating-database-using-a-string?noredirect=1#comment42482634_26973682)

Answer (score 3):

```
db.update(TABLE_AI, values,KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME  + " = ?",
                new String[] {ai.getAccount_name()});
```

Try this one.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code,

```
int i=db.update(TABLE_AI, values, KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME + " =? " , new String[] {ai.getAccount_name()});  

System.out.println("i="+i);
```

If i>0, then some updated, else no row update.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your kind help.  I can't solve this problem without your help.

I change my code adding ' ' to the value.

```
db.update(TABLE_AI, values, KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME + " = " + name, null);

db.update(TABLE_AI, values, KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME + " = '" + name+"'", null);
```

I should say thanks to you early, but I have similar problems in my DBAdapter.java, so I had busy time fixing it.

And other answers work just fine as well

```
db.update(TABLE_AI, values,KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME  + " = ?",
            new String[] {ai.getAccount_name()});
```